# Three.js: How can I convert a Scene into an MPG4 Video?

Tags: java, javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I have a three.js scene:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

The scene contains many objects which are animated. My goal is to export the animation as a mpg4 video.

My questions:

1. How can I export a scene to get an mpg4 video?
2. Should I do the export on the client side or on the server side?

Edit:

I need it to run on a website or on a Java based server. No browser extensions please.

Answer (score 5):

Check this github repo, I think it does exactly that:
https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30459466)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this Chrome extension to record a `<canvas>`:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rendercan/enlfmgpmfaibbeoelliknejffljklemg

This will produce a compressed file with all the frames. With that file uncompressed you can use `ffmpeg` to combine all the frames in one single video like this:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -i canvas-%09d.png out.mp4
```

If the command line route intimidates you, I think After Effects or similar allow you to do that too.

Comment: I need it to run on a website.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then maybe you can write a server with node.js and send images with timestamp via PUT.

Comment: Then write your solution in Java. Sheesh

Comment: Looks like this Chrome extension is gone now

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `FFmpeg` library you could try something like:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < frames; i ++ ) {

    player.render( currentTime );

    const num = i.toString().padStart( 5, '0' );
    ffmpeg.FS( 'writeFile', `tmp.${num}.png`, await fetchFile( canvas.toDataURL() ) );
    currentTime += 1 / fps;

    progress.setValue( ( i / frames ) * 0.5 );

}
```

[Github Source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/3e5d141bcc05e0e4d3d3aa760d9be4329c7239b8/editor/js/Sidebar.Project.Video.js#L90-L100)